# oracle timestamp equivalent data type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I was trying to insert  timestamp data of oracle to postgres via csv. at oracle side the datatype of column is timestamp and postgres as well I defined datatype as timestamp and still facing the following error.
invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "13-AUG-21 04.54.01.290199 AM"

so, how can we import timestamp data of oracle into postgres?? what datatype must be used to define timestamp column of oracle at postgres.

Comment: You need to tell your CSV importer the format of your timestamp strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `TIMESTAMP` data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value TIMESTAMP );
```

Then a timestamp literal:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( TIMESTAMP '2021-08-13 04:54:01.290199' );
```

*Oracle db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=48405ec24f22ac3a484c60aa229a43bc)*

*PostgreSQL db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=48405ec24f22ac3a484c60aa229a43bc)*

---

PostgreSQL appears to support conversion of a string literal in multiple formats:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( '2021-08-13 04:54:01.290199' );
INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( '13-AUG-21 04:54:01.290199 AM' );
INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( '2021-AUG-13 04:54:01.290199 AM' );
```

But doesn't like it when you use a full stop `.` to separate the time components.

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( '13-AUG-21 04.54.01.290199 AM' );
```

Which fails with:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "13-AUG-21 04.54.01.290199 AM"
> LINE 1: INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( '13-AUG-21 04.54.0...
> ```

If you want to input a non-standard format then you can use `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (
  value
) VALUES (
  TO_TIMESTAMP('13-AUG-21 04.54.01.290199 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SS.US AM' )
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a8a9a6124dd51ac863ba4abc5bc9a71f)*

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all timestamp values with a simple find/replace regex:

- Find: `(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.`
- Replace: `$1:$2:$3.`

I used Sublime Text to apply the conversion
in a CSV file, you can use any other tool.

[image]